# Sums of three cubes in two ways

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory

For any positive $N>0$, define a number $s(N)$ as

\begin{equation}
s(N)=\#\{(x_1, x_2,x_3, y_1,y_2,y_3)\in \mathbb{Z}^6: |x_i|\leq N, |y_i|\leq N, \sum x_i^3=\sum y_i^3\}.
\end{equation}

I heard that a conjecture states that $s(N)\lesssim N^3$ and Luogeng Hua made some progress on this problem by showing that
$$
s(N)\lesssim N^{7/2}.
$$

What's the current state of this conjecture? And where can I find a reference for Hua's work?

Comment: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/96605.pdf